# How do I make subplots in Pygal?

Tags: python, plot, data-visualization, pygal

I'm making a couple of radar plots on Pygal and want to have subplots. Each plot looks identical to the code below, with slight changes to which dataframe I'm using. I know on matplotlib or seaborn, there are ways to create subplots quite easily, but I'm having trouble doing so on Pygal.

```
radar1 = pygal.Radar()
radar1.title =  'Site_A'

radar1.x_labels=['A','B','C',
                 'D','E','F']

for i in np.arange(len(d['Site_A'])):
    radar1.add(str(d['Site_A']['Location'].iloc[i]),d[ 'Site_A'].iloc[i,[3,5,7,9,11,13]].values.tolist())

radar1
```

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47416439/12870513

Answer (score 0):

Just keep adding it with a different name of the plot or data.

For example:

**radar1.add(plot1)**

**radar1.add(plot2)**

**radar1.add(plot3)**